# Selecting Active roles from denormalized table with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bit of a garbage table that I need to extract data from.

```
 Name        | Person# | Assignment_Status | Group
 --------------------------------------------------
 Smith, John | 1234567 | NLE               | G1
 Smith, John | 1234567 | Active            | G2
 Jones, Jane | 7654321 | Active            | G1
 James, Jack | 9876541 | LOA               | G3
 Peep, Laura | 6549871 | ServiceLOA        | G1
 Some, One   | 3219875 | NLE               | G2
```

Every time a person moves groups their current assignment_status gets set to NLE and a new record gets create to set the assignment_status to Active for the new group. When a person leaves the company they also set the assignment_status to NLE. This table does not have a Unique row ID nor does it have a date stamp.

I need a query that reduces the table to 1 record per employee and if the employee has multiple records I need the Assignment_Status that is not NLE. For example, John Smith should show as active for G2.

My first attempt was:

```
 SELECT *
 INTO #TempAssignments
 FROM
    (SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aID) AS ID,
       Name,
       Person#,
       (CASE WHEN Assignment_Status='NLE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aID,
       Group
     FROM
       tblAssignments)
```

With the data in a temp table then I created a second query to select the MIN of ID, the MIN of aID and GROUP BY Name and Person# then joined that back to the temp table to get the Group for the given ID.

This seems to work however this is a solution that needs to be deployed in multiple reports so I was wondering if there isn't a more compact way of doing this.

Comment: If you don't have indexes or your table is small it is better to use `ROW_NUMBER()` (without `GROUP BY`, of course). If your table is big and you can create an index on `(Person#, Assignment_Status)` and, even better, if you have a separate small table with the list of all people, then it could be better to use `CROSS APPLY`. By "better" I mean faster here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query:

```
SELECT Name, Person#, [Group]
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Person#, [Group],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person#, Name 
                            ORDER BY CASE 
                                      WHEN Assignment_Status <> 'NLE' THEN 0 
                                      ELSE 1 
                                     END) AS rn
   FROM tblAssignments ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

will select one record for each employee, as identified by a `Person#, Name` value pair. If the employee has multiple records, then a record with `Assignment_Status` that is not `NLE` will be selected.